# AngularJS parsing JSON by template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JSON string (`jsonString`).
I will need to format this string, according my template (`myTemplate`).

Is there a way to make this via JavaScript in AngularJS? Not in HTML!

```
var jsonString = {
    comp_code: 100,
    comp_name: 'Test company',
    comp_url: 'Some url',
    comp_note: 'Some notes',
    comp_acc: '1002000'
};

var myTemplate = 'Code: {{comp_code}}, Name: {{comp_name}}, Company account: {{comp_acc}}';
```

I want a get output string such as this:

```
'Code: 100, Name: Test company, Company account: 1002000'
```

Comment: Your `jsonString` isn't a JSON string. It's just a JavaScript object.

Comment: for me looks like a typical case for a directive. but you did not really tell what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and call variable directly from inside a string.

```js
var jsonString = {
  comp_code: 100,
  comp_name: 'Test company',
  comp_url: 'Some url',
  comp_note: 'Some notes',
  comp_acc: '1002000'
};

var myTemplate = `Code: ${jsonString.comp_code}, Name: ${jsonString.comp_name}, Company account: ${jsonString.comp_acc}`;
console.log(myTemplate)
```